# Data annotation validation does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I am developing an application in MVC using Smart Admin in which I use data annotations for validation purpose. My code is:

```
public  class EmployeeDTO
{          

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z '-.(-,)-/&]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my view is

```
        <script src="~/SmartAdmin/js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

        @model HBSeworld.Admin.DTO.EmployeeDTO

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        }

        <section class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-1" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-custombutton="false">

            <header>
                <span class="widget-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <h2>Create Employee</h2>
            </header>

            <div>
                <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                </div>

                <section class="widget-body no-padding">

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "order-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "smart-form" }))
                    { 
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                                <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <section class="label col col-2" style="text-align: right">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                                    </section>
                                    <section class="col col-4">
                                        <label class="input">
                                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @placeholder = "Enter Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                                        </label>
                                    </section>
                      </div>
                   </fieldset>
<div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <input type="submit" id="create" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 25px; width: 45px;" />
                    <input type="button" style="height:25px; width:45px;" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")    '"/>
                </div>
            }
                 </section>
               </div>
             </section>
```

Now, my question is that, when I click on `Create` button, data annotation message is displayed properly but at the same time the control goes to controller, instead it should be on same view and have to display data annotation message. How to prevent this? Any solution?

Comment: Do you mean the browser should stay at the same page instead of redirecting to the controller? Or the controller redirects to another page? Looking at your html code it is clear that clicking the button will result in a HTTP POST sent to the server.

Comment: When I didn't fill anything in `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @placeholder = "Enter Name" })` it means data annotation message should have to display.Here in my case, message is displayed but it doesn't prevent to redirect to controller.I want to prevent that in case when I didn't fill anything and try to click on `Create` button

Comment: In that case, your description and title is wrong. Your problem is not about data annotation not working, it is about stopping the view from redirect when invalid data is detected.